# Facebook app internal setup freezes my app login in android

Tags: android, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Looks like I have same problem, as described here:
[Facebook SDK for Android - first login is very slow / takes a very long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521516/facebook-sdk-for-android-first-login-is-very-slow-takes-a-very-long-time)

here is what I'm doing:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("Auth_type", Constants.AUTH_TYPE_FACEBOOK).apply();
            processFacebookToken(loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(FacebookLoginActivity.this, FacebookLoginActivity.this.getResources().getText(R.string.facebook_login_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    });

ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>(2);
permissions.add("public_profile");
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, permissions);
```

And if fb app was installed, but never launched, my app freezes because of this as I think: [image: this is native fb app first launch]
this is native fb app first launch

Would be perfect, if it shows inside my app, but app freezes for this "setup" period if fb app was not launched and user try to login in my app. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Please, can you show `processFacebookToken(loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());` method, or explain what it is doing. Also, try to comment it and run app without it. Because your code looks fine, but this method is suspisious.

Comment: freeze happens before fb login dialogue shown and this method performed. Happening only on low-end devices.